# How do you create a shim component in angular that is used for server but uses regular component for browser?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am trying to use two different components based on if its on browser or server. I am attempting to follow https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/main/docs/gotchas.md.

```
// example.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'example-component',
  template: `<library-component></library-component>`, // this is provided by a third-party lib
  // that causes issues rendering on Universal
})
export class ExampleComponent {}
```

```
// app.module.ts
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ExampleComponent} from './example.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ExampleComponent],
})
```

```
// browser-app.module.ts
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {LibraryModule} from 'some-lib';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [AppModule, LibraryModule],
})
```

```
// library-shim.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'library-component',
  template: '',
})
export class LibraryShimComponent {}
```

```
// server.app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LibraryShimComponent } from './library-shim.component';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [AppModule],
  declarations: [LibraryShimComponent],
})
export class ServerAppModule {}
```

Trying to setup modules where server and browser modules import app.module isn't working for me. It seems that since the selector library-component is not declared in app.module it causes an error

```
If 'library-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module
```

I tried to do a simpler project to see if I can create a submodule that uses an undeclared template name and declare it in the route module that imports the sub module. I had the same problem. Is there a way to create a module that expects a template name to be declared by the module importing it?

Thought this may be related, https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/2481 and maybe it can't be done and documentation is just wrong, but since its been up for so long I would be surprised it is still up?

Answer (score 0):

Angular V14, things I learned as trying to solve this.

I could not find a way to do the server, browser and shared modules where shared module uses a component but does not declare and instead is declared in parent module (server or browser).

Ended up using the answer given in the github issues post https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/2481. It is a simple solution for using different components based on if running in browser or server using environment variables.

### Switch Component using System Variables

Add two environment files environment-server.ts and environment-server.prod.ts.

Add the following to environment-server.prod.ts and update other environment files as needed (changing true or false if production and if server)

```json
//environment-server.prod.ts
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  isServer:true
};
```

Modify angular.json server fileReplacement

```json
// angular.json
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment-server.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
```

Modify angular.json server fileReplacement

```json
// angular.json
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment-server.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
```

This will change the environment.ts file depending on if browser or server is being ran. We can then use that to change the component used.

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
...
  declarations: [
    ...
    environment.isServer==true? BrowserComponent: ServerComponent
  ],
```

The server component will be used first then replaced with browser component, so you may have to turn off JavaScript to see the server component is rendering correctly. If you don't see anything after turning off JavaScript, but it was working with JavaScript before, things like using `Observers` and other unsupported features will keep from rendering page.